# How to create parametrized style in xaml without custom control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two styles, which are almost identical:

```
<Style x:Key="CancelButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <!-- gigantic common code -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- more common code -->
                <Path Data="DIFFERENT_VALUE_A"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="OkButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <!-- gigantic common code -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- more common code -->
                <Path Data="DIFFERENT_VALUE_B"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to extract the common code ("style template"), and then use it like that:

```
<Style x:Key="OkButtonStyle" Base="PathButtonStyle" PathData="DIFFERENT_VALUE_B" />
```

EDIT:
As I specified in title, **I don't want to create my own control**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define your `ControlTemplate` objects separately in `Resources`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate1">
    <!-- different part -->
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate2">
    <!-- different part -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Create one `Style` for the common parts:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <!-- gigantic common code -->
</Style>
```

Then base your new styles on that one, referencing your new `ControlTemplate`s:

```
<Style x:Key="CancelButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ControlTemplate1}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="OkButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ControlTemplate2}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It's better than total duplication, but I still end up with lots of common code in ControlTemplate ("more common code" in my question)

Comment: I made my example clearer. Your common code is only written once and only the different parts are written separately... just like you asked. EDIT>> Oh, I didn't see your code changes before

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tag to pass the PathData:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <!-- gigantic common code -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- more common code -->
                <Path Data="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then set the Tag in your individual Style:

```
<Style x:Key="CancelButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="MY PAth A" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="OkButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="MY PAth B" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It's dirty, but meets my conditions (no custom controls)

Comment: I agree that it's a little dirty. Another way would be to do the same but instead of using tag use an attached property that you created. That would be a little more "clean" but would require you to create the attached property ....

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Button, which derives from the Wpf-Button and has the property PathData:

```
public class PathButton:Button
{
    public string PathData {get;set;}
}
```

The your style could be like:

```
<Style x:Key="PathButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ns:PathButton}" >
    <!-- gigantic common code -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- more common code -->
                <Path Data="{TemplateBinding PathData}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

To use it you have to do this:

```
<ns:PathButton Style="{StaticResource PathButtonStyle}" PathData="M200 200 100 100 L0 0"/>
```

Or you create your own `Custom Control`, the way would be the same.

The adventage here is no matter how many different buttons you want to use, there always will be just one `Style` in your resources and one class (`PathButton`).
You just have to change the `PathData`-property of your `PathButton` to change it's appereance.

Comment: As I specified in title, I don't want to create any custom controls (including custom buttons)

Comment: Sry, didnt read that :D...Why dont you want to use your own control? It would be less code than the other way.